# How to handle route parameters in Angular Universal for Java

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot, angular-universal

I'm working on an Angular 5 app with Server Side Rendering using Angular Universal for Java ([See the project here](https://github.com/swaechter/angularj-universal)). I have a parameterized route defined in Angular as `/person/:personId`, and this works fine when rendered in the browser but not on the server.

In my spring-mvc controller I have

```
@GetMapping({"/"})
public ModelAndView showHome() {
    return new ModelAndView("/");
}

@GetMapping({"/person/{personId}"})
public ModelAndView showFeedbackDetail(HttpServletRequest request, 
   @PathVariable("person") String personId) {
    return new ModelAndView("/person/:personId");
}
```

And in my application.properties:

```
# Define all application routes
angularjuniversal.routes=/,/person/:personId

# point to the SPA index.html page
angularjuniversal.indexResourcePath=/static/index.html

# point to the server application
angularjuniversal.serverBundleResourcePath=/server.js
```

I'm not really sure how to the `{personId}` parameter can get passed to Angular for rendering.

Statically defined routes work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question [here](https://github.com/swaechter/angularj-universal/issues/21).

In short, it seems that 0.0.2 of the angularj-universal library doesn't support parameterized routing. It does look like it will be fixed in an upcoming release. This can be fixed in the mean time by copying the latest implementation of [AngularJUniversalView](https://github.com/swaechter/angularj-universal/blob/0.0.2/angularj-universal-spring-boot-starter/src/main/java/ch/swaechter/angularjuniversal/springboot/starter/AngularJUniversalView.java) and [AngularJUniversalViewResolver](https://github.com/swaechter/angularj-universal/blob/0.0.2/angularj-universal-spring-boot-starter/src/main/java/ch/swaechter/angularjuniversal/springboot/starter/AngularJUniversalViewResolver.java) and overriding the ViewResolver that's currently in the spring context with the copied AngularJUniversalViewResolver implementation.